# Циклы и рекурсия

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу остановить цикл в while True, break не срабатывает помогите плз.

```
x = []

def xxx(a):
    while True:
        if (a % 10) < 1:
            print(x)
            break

        x.append(a // 10)
        xxx(x[-1])


xxx(int(input("Vvedete cheslo")))
```

Comment: хочу число разбить на числа и записать в массив, пример 345 --- массив: 345, 34, 5

Comment: Рекурсия тут явно лишняя: `xxx(x[-1])`

Comment: А как из `345` стало 345, 34, 5? Понял бы если, `3, 4, 5` или `345, 34, 3`. Можете объяснить?

Comment: @КириллМаликов либо рекурсию используйте, либо цикл, определитесь)

Comment: @gil9red, да, вы правы, ряд я не правильно написал. Код поправил сам, получилось.

Comment: @dhvcc определился, рекурсия, код поправил и получилось))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция с циклом:

```py
def xxx(num):
  while num > 0:
    yield num
    num //= 10

print(list(xxx(3564)))
```

Функция с рекурсией:

```py
def xxx(num):
  if num <= 0:
    return []
  else:
    return [num] + xxx(num//10)

print(xxx(3564))
```

Вывод:

```
[3564, 356, 35, 3]
```

Comment: Большое спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Через цикл:

```
def split_num(num: int) -> list:
    items = []

    while True:
        items.append(num)

        num //= 10
        if num == 0:
            break

    return items


items = split_num(345)
print(items)
# [345, 34, 3]
```

Comment: огромное спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Ну или так

```
def split_num(num: int) -> list:
    items = [str(num)]
    for _ in items[0]:
        items.append(items[-1][:-1])

    return [int(x) for x in items if x != ""]

items = split_num(345)
print(items)
```

Вариант конечно извращенный и медленный, но потешный. Или нет?